# StateFlow is updated but not collected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I'm currently learning about the new Android stack (MVVM, compose, kotlin Flow/StateFlow), and I'm having trouble debugging a StateFlow where the value is updated, but I have no sign of collection from the composable.

It's a generic question, but I didn't find any solution to my problem by searching on my own.

Does anybody have an idea about what could disturb a StateFlow? I'm letting my code below:

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AuthViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val navigationManager: NavigationManager,
    private val interactor: AuthInteractor
): BaseViewModel() {

    companion object {
        val TAG: String = AuthViewModel::class.java.simpleName
    }

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(AuthenticationState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<AuthenticationState> = _uiState

    fun handleEvent(event: AuthenticationEvent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "new event: $event")
        when (event) {
            is AuthenticationEvent.GoToRegistering -> navigateToRegistering()
            is AuthenticationEvent.Register -> registerAccount(event)
            is AuthenticationEvent.SnackbarMessage -> showSnackBar(event.message, event.type)
        }
    }

    private fun navigateToRegistering() {
        navigationManager.navigate(NavigationDirections.Authentication.registering)
    }

    private fun registerAccount(event: AuthenticationEvent.Register) {
        Log.v(TAG, "register account")
        _uiState.value.build {
            isLoading = true
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            Log.v(TAG, "launching request")
            val exceptionMessage = interactor.registerUser(event.login, event.password)
            Log.v(TAG, "response received, launching state from viewmodel")

            _uiState.value.build {
                exceptionMessage?.let {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Exception is not null")
                    isFailure = true
                    snackbarMessage = interactor.selectRegisterError(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

UI Component:

```
@Composable
fun Authentication(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: AuthViewModel,
    type: AuthenticationType
) {
    val state by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    Log.v("Authentication", "new state: $state, type = $type")

    BackHandler(enabled = true) {
        viewModel.handleEvent(AuthenticationEvent.Back)
    }

    state.snackbarMessage?.let { resourceId ->
        val message = stringResource(resourceId)
        Log.e("Authentication", "error: $message")
        viewModel.handleEvent(AuthenticationEvent.SnackbarMessage(message, SnackbarType.ERROR))
    }

    if (state.isAuthenticated) {
        // TODO: launch main screen
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.isRegistered) {
        // TODO: launch login event
    }

    AuthenticationContent(
        modifier = modifier,
        type = type,
        viewModel = viewModel,
        state = state
    )
}
```

State Data Class:

```
data class AuthenticationState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val isFailure: Boolean = false,
    val isRegistered: Boolean = false,
    val isAuthenticated: Boolean = false,
    @StringRes val snackbarMessage: Int? = null
)  {

    fun build(block: Builder.() -> Unit) = Builder(this).apply(block).build()

    class Builder(uiModel: AuthenticationState) {
        var isLoading = uiModel.isLoading
        var isFailure = uiModel.isFailure
        var isRegistered = uiModel.isRegistered
        var isAuthenticated = uiModel.isAuthenticated
        var snackbarMessage = uiModel.snackbarMessage

        fun build(): AuthenticationState {
            return AuthenticationState(
                isLoading,
                isFailure,
                isRegistered,
                isAuthenticated,
                snackbarMessage
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of this code are you expecting to cause a collection of the flow?

Comment: On the UI Component: `val state by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()`
As I mentionned, I'm learning so maybe I'm missing a step

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing the updates like this:

```
_uiState.value.build {
    isLoading = true
}
```

This code takes current value of `uiState` and calls build function on it. Build function creates **new instance** of `AuthenticationState`, but you don't do anything with that new instance and it's discarded. You have to set this new instance to be the new value of your StateFlow, like this:

```
_uiState.value = _uiState.value.build {}
// or this:
_uiState.update { current -> current.build {} }
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about update function, now it works fine.